# Enconding of file sent using FLASK function send_file

Tags: python, rest, flask

When we use flask function send_file, what is the actual encoding of the file sent on the REST body with mimetype image/jpeg? It is possible to send the file using a base64 enconding?

Line of code:

```
send_file("logo.jpg", mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being sent as binary on the wire, e.g. the HTTP response will be

```
200 OK
Content-type: image/jpeg
Content-length: 1234

����JFIF��
          ExifMM*
$���1�2��i��%�OnePlusONEPLUS A6013
```

etc.

You can manually base64 encode the data if your app requires it.

Comment: How can you manually base64 encode the jpg image and sent it using the send_file function?

Comment: You can't use `send_file()` while manually encoding the image. You'd read the image, encode it, then send it as a regular response.